# Changing owner as root for the directory

Tags: linux

I have my sd card and I have two partitions BOOT and rootfs. BOOT has the owner as user and rootfs has the owner as root. But i want to have owner of the directory BOOT be root and rootfs be the user. What has to be done?

When I am using the command `sudo chown -R root BOOT/` I am getting an error "operation not permitted".

Comment: Command looks fine, except that you might also want to set group to "root" by specifying  `sudo chown -R root:root BOOT/`. If you are being told that operation is not permitted, than you have no super user rights, simple as that. If you perform `sudo touch 1.txt` you get the same error?

Comment: but following error message is coming... `chown: changing ownership of 'BOOT/.Trash-1000/info/System Volume Information.trashinfo': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of 'BOOT/.Trash-1000/info': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of 'BOOT/.Trash-1000/files/System Volume Information/IndexerVolumeGuid': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of 'BOOT/.Trash-1000/files/System Volume Information': Operation not permitted`

Comment: I'm 100% sure `.Trash-1000` should not be present on your BOOT partition, it's a trashbin folder, you might as well try to delete it with `sudo rm -rf BOOT/.Trash-1000/`. How about other files? Did all relevant files change an owner? Check it with `ls -l BOOT/`

Comment: `ls -lart
total 8
drwsrwxrwx+ 5 root   root   4096 Aug  1 11:25 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 janani janani 4096 Aug  1 11:46 .` nope when i checked with 
`ls -lart` these are present in my BOOT folder and the same error message when i tried to change owner... `chown: changing ownership of 'BOOT/': Operation not permitted`

Comment: Is the partition by any chance a FAT partition? FAT does not support file ownership, but you can fake it via the `uid=id` mount option. This sets the owner of all files on the file system to _id_.

Comment: Check SELinux isn't active also.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that  your /boot partition and your / partition actually are not mounted in ro mode and if you are operating from a live system then you can't change that but if it is a barebone system then you could change it.

run `mount` and post output of the command
or better run `mount | grep -i boot` and check do you have `ro` flag which mean that your /boot partition is mounted in ReadOnly mode.

If its not a live system then you could run `mount -o remount,rw /boot`

if you get answer like 
`cannot remount /boot read-write, is write-protected` that mean that you are trying to mount ro volume as rw like the partition on CD/DVD or the iso image that was dd into the usb drive.